# Parsed JSON Data not showing up in listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I have parsed my json code into my app and it show up in the logg but it doesnt show up in my listview.
Code that should lode the json and put the json into the listview:
http://pastebin.com/09WRD3D9
Activity of that code:
http://pastebin.com/1xc8UDYQ
Json:
http://pastebin.com/9tpxYJns
Also on http://nijdeken.com/test.php

Hope someone can help me with this. (Yes I have a working service handler).
I have used the same code for another project but that API had an Array in front of it (Lessons) and mine doesnt but it isnt that.

Greetings

Comment: I cannot access the links. Post your code in the question.

Comment: http://nijdeken.com/map/code (is the code)
http://nijdeken.com/map/xml (Is the XML)

Comment: dont mind the getRooster part its disabled for the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

// Getting JSON Array node
contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("");
```

to

```
contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

EDIT:

Found the issue - you are using wrong keys. The first letter is capital in the HTTP response, while the constants in your code a lower case.

Your app should be working after you add these changes to the previous ones:

```
private static final String TAG_thing = "Thing";
private static final String TAG_place = "Place";
private static final String TAG_time = "Time";
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Think I found the issue, could you try the new changes (i.e. in combination with the previous ones). :)

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU SO FREAKING MUCH!!